# Web page cannot display some images

Tags: image, .htaccess

My host uses Apache with .htaccess.

The web page is PHP-based.

The PHP files load just fine. The images are an issue.

A few are OK but most are not. They are all in a folder /jpg off the root.

Some are png others jpg.

All the images are like this:

```
<p class="Regular" align="center"><img class="img-responsive"  max-width="90%" height="auto" src="/jpg/topimage.jpg" ><br/><br/>
```

If I replace topimage.jpg with say image20.jpg, even though image20.jpg is in the  jpg folder, it does not display.

I thought, maybe this is due somehow to caching? (not sure why). I try with Chrome, Firefox and Opera.

My computer runs Windows 10.

On Android it is even worse. Only one image appears.

An almost identical web page is available from another URL and the images there (the same ones) display just fine.

The properties of the folders in .htaccess seem OK.

Where would I look next?

I replaced a one of the png image files with a similarly named jpg. So \jpg\image2.png is now \jpg\image2.jpg. Here's the img html:

```
<img class="img-responsive"  max-width="40%" height="auto" src="/jpg/image2.jpg">
```

And image2.jpg is in the /jpg folder off the root.

If I edit (on Apache) the php file and change image2 to image1, image1 appears. Back to image2.jpg and again the placeholder.

I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: First, check in your browser dev tools (console and network panel), why it can not load those images - does it get a 404, a 500 internal server error, …? Then, check the server’s log files, access & error, and check what you find there regarding those requests.

Comment: no error message. It's like the src was pointing to something that didn't exist.

Comment: Do you have this only local, or “live” somewhere we could take a look at it?

Comment: http://alkemized.com/

Comment: There does not seem to be an image named `image20.jpg`, but one named `image20.JPG` instead - http://alkemized.com/jpg/image20.JPG Windows treats file names case-insensitive, but other operating systems (and likely your site is hosted on a Linux- rather than a Windows system) don’t.

Comment: true but the current page at alkemized/index.php doesn't reference image20. It only references \jpg\image1.jpg .

Comment: It might just be that while for me on WinSCP my changes are pretty fast, perhaps on the server side they are slower? Now things seem to be OK, which is weird but, whatever.

Comment: The server just emits 404s for most all the images. Doesn't matter if they are jpgs or pngs or what folder they are in. And yet, from another web page they are accessed. The file and folder properties seem correct. I did use dev tools.

Comment: I'm not sure why but I changed the image to jpg. The png was getting a status code of 300. Changed the image (via Photoshop) to jpg, cleared the cache and it works.